# color nodes in igraph ggraph r

Tags: r, nodes, igraph, ggraph

I'd like to color the nodes of a graph based on an attribute in the original dataframe. But I think I haven't "carried through" that aestetic variable to the graph.

Example here that works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

data <-
  tibble(
    from = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"),
    to = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2),
    type = c("X", "Y", "Y", "X", "Y", "X")
  )

graph <-
  graph_from_data_frame(data)

ggraph(graph,
       layout = "fr") +
  geom_node_point() +
  geom_edge_link()
```

I'd like something like `geom_node_point(aes(color = type))`, but haven't made type findable in the graph?

Comment: I think that `type` is an edge attribute, not a node one. Each row of `data` defines an edge, and to each of those edges corresponds a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you added the `type` column as an edge-attribute whereas `geom_node_point` expects a vertex-attribute (see `?graph_from_data_frame`: *Additional columns are considered as edge attributes.*).
Another issue is that `type` is not consistent for either node column (e.g. `a` is associated with type `X` and also `Y`, the same is true for node `2`).

To address the first issue you could add additional vertex information to the `vertices` argument of the `graph_from_data_frame` function.

The simplest solution to address both issues is to add the type attribute after creating the graph:

```
 data <-
  tibble(
    from = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"),
    to = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2)
  )

graph <- graph_from_data_frame(data)
V(graph)$type <- bipartite.mapping(graph)$type
```

The `bipartite.mapping` function adds either `TRUE` or `FALSE` consistently to each vertex of different type.

Comment: thank you! totally blanked on it being an edge attribute!!